# Python: converting Trip duration of h min sec and leave only minute count

Tags: python, numpy, time, pandas, duration

I am new to python and programming (so please go easy) and hope someone can help.
I have bike trip duration as dtype: object
    *Duration
14h 26min. 2sec.
0h 8min. 34sec.
0h 12min. 17sec.*

I would ideally like to create a new column holding the calculated minute duration as an integer. So h needs *60, and seconds rounded.So I would have:
*Duration
866
9
12*

I am having trouble it the first hurdle of splitting and getting just the digit.
I have had some joy in splitting with this:

```
def ConvertDuration(Minutes):
    return Minutes.split(' ')[0].split('.')[1].strip()
WashBike['DurationMin'] = pd.DataFrame({'Duration':WashBike['Duration'].apply(ConvertDuration)})
```

I can play around with positions and create one column each for h, min and sec. 
however string character will remain. would I need to do another split to further separate and remove characters then?
I have also tried to strip the characters with the following:

```
WashBike['DurationInt'] = WashBike['Duration'].str.strip(' ').str.strip('.').str.strip('hHmMiInNsSeEcC')
```

I have not been able to get to the stage of putting the values into a single figure minute unit measurement. I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
WashBike['DurationMn'] = WashBike['Duration'].split(' ').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1] + int(x[2].round()) ))
```

Although I am not able to get this far.

I have spent 2 days looking through stackoverflow and others. I have found plenty about datetime etc. While i have tried to convert Duration to hh:mm:ss, I'm not sure if its the correct course. Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Ken

Comment: First question:  I assume Duration 14h 26min. 2sec. 0h 8min. 34sec. 0h 12min. 17sec.  is a text field?  "Duration 14h 26min. 2sec. 0h 8min. 34sec. 0h 12min. 17sec."

Comment: Hi Alexander. Yes it is a text field. sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: Notice where the quotes are placed.  Is Duration the title of the column and each time value an element?  E.g. "14h 26min. 2sec.", "0h 8min. 34sec.", "0h 12min. 17sec.".  Or is it all one long string?

Comment: Hi Alexander, sorry for not replying sooner. Yes, Duration = Title with each time value an element. The 2 answers provided give me what I am looking for. However, if you have/want to contribute, I'd be happy to receive advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to do it without using any date-parsing modules.

A single-liner - you could extract numbers from via regex and `apply` on the `duration` column like   *split into multilines for readability*

```
(df['Duration']
 .apply(lambda x: sum([a*int(b) 
                       for a,b in zip([60., 1., 1./60],
                                      re.findall(r'\d+', x))]))
)
```

Essentially, for a string like `'4h 26min. 2sec.'` you're first finding pattern `re.findall(r'\d+', x)` i.e `[4, 26, 2]` now multiple this with minutes `[60., 1., 1./60]` and `sum` the values.

Let's say `df` is like

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': ['4h 26min. 2sec.',
                                        '0h 8min. 34sec.',
                                        '0h 12min. 17sec.']})
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
           Duration
0   4h 26min. 2sec.
1   0h 8min. 34sec.
2  0h 12min. 17sec.
```

Then, Minutes can be extracted like

```
In [9]: (df['Duration']
   ...:  .apply(lambda x: sum([a*int(b)
   ...:                        for a,b in zip([60., 1., 1./60],
   ...:                                       re.findall(r'\d+', x))]))
   ...: )
Out[9]:
0    266.033333
1      8.566667
2     12.283333
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

---

For readability sake, you can also create a custom function `minutes`

```
def minutes(string):
    pattern = re.findall(r'\d+', string)
    minutes_mul =  [a*int(b) for a,b in zip([60., 1., 1./60], pattern)]
    return sum(minutes_mul)
```

And, then apply on

```
df['Duration'].apply(minutes)
```

Comment: Hello John Galt and @Jeff. A big Irish thank you. I had tried various functions but patterns never came into my mind. something I will remember for the future. Working with Time is something I'm not use to and the link Jeff provided is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is straightforward frequency conversion, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion)

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': ['4h 26min. 2sec.',
                                        '0h 8min. 34sec.',
                                        '0h 12min. 17sec.']})

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
           Duration
0   4h 26min. 2sec.
1   0h 8min. 34sec.
2  0h 12min. 17sec.
```

These are almost in standard form, just zonk the .

```
In [18]: pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration.str.replace('\.',''))                        
Out[18]: 
0   04:26:02
1   00:08:34
2   00:12:17
Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

A float result in minutes

```
In [19]: pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration.str.replace('\.','')) / np.timedelta64(1,'m')
Out[19]: 
0    266.033333
1      8.566667
2     12.283333
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

This truncates

```
In [20]: pd.to_timedelta(df.Duration.str.replace('\.','')).astype('timedelta64[m]')
Out[20]: 
0    266
1      8
2     12
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```